System.getProperty("non-english.path") returns wrong charset characters when starts java app with -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
On Windows 10, I set the default character to UTF-8 from Control Pane > Clock And Region > Region > Administrative > Change System locale , check Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support and restart the machine.
On starting a java(jdk1.8.0_212) application with the following command(中区 is some Chinese characters):
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dv8.path="D:\\中区path" App

the value of System.getProperty("v8.path") is a weild D:\涓尯path not D:\\中区path, thus cause the app crash due to a NoSuchFileException.
How to make System.getProperty return the correct characters?

Update:

I use Windows cmd, and run chcp prints:
Active code page: 65001


Character values for System.getProperty("v8.path").toCharArray():
'D' 68
':' 58
'\\' 92
'\\' 92
'涓' 28051
'\uE15E' 57694
'尯' 23599
'p' 112
'a' 97
't' 116
'h' 104




Could add more info to the question: which terminal do you use, and its code page setting (chcp), and character values for System.getProperty("v8.path").toCharArray() (expected and actual). Unrelated, the terminal would not need two slash  \\.

You don't want to rely on a Windows console for accurate support of Unicode. You can of course put those properties into a file and load them into a Properties in your app. Later versions of java (why are you using such an old one?) allow for argfiles for passing arguments

You face a mojibake case (example in Python for its universal intelligibility): print('中区'.encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'gb18030')) returns 涓尯…

You have posted your solution at the end of your question - don't do that! Instead, post your solution as an answer to your own question. Also, if you are satisfied with your solution, accept that answer. This helps others in the community who encounter an issue similar to yours.

Josefz is right. Given the following java code:
Charset charset = Charset.forName("gb18030");
ByteBuffer buffer = charset.encode(CharBuffer.wrap(System.getProperty("v8.path")));

CharBuffer decode = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.decode(buffer);
System.out.println(decode.toString());  

The result is the expected value:
D:\中区path

